# Django Gunicorn-Nginx 504 gateway timeout

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, django, gunicorn

I have read a lot of articles about `gunicorn` & `nginx` timeout configs .

I have some requests on my website which take longer than 30 seconds . 
I changed all `gunicorn` timeouts to 3 seconds but still getting

> 504 gateway timeout

error after 30 seconds .

Gunicorn Config File :

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/Lav/project
ExecStart=/home/user/LavEnv/project/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --keep-alive 3 --timeout 3 --graceful-timeout 3 --bind unix:/home/user/Lav/project/project.socket project.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Nginx Config File :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 178.63.217.47;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root project_root;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root project_root;
    }
    location /files/ {
        root project_root;
    }


    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout   300;
        proxy_send_timeout      300;
        proxy_read_timeout      300;
        include         uwsgi_params;
        proxy_pass      http://unix:/project_root/StoreManager.socket;
    }
}
```

Timeouts work well when i run the website directly from gunicorn (--bind 0.0.0.0:8000) , this problem occurs with nginx-gunicorn .

How can i set timeout to a value more than 30 seconds ?

Comment: add inside location 
 block `fastcgi_read_timeout 60;` http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_read_timeout

Comment: fix: `proxy_pass http://unix:/project_root/StoreManager.socket;`  should be: `proxy_pass 
 unix:/project_root/StoreManager.socket;`  which in Your case is: `proxy_pass 
 unix:/home/user/Lav/project/project.socket;`